# Executing scripts with bash from vim

Tags: bash, vim

I'm trying to get vim to execute the script I'm editing with a key mapping, say <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>, so I used this in `vimrc`

`:map <C-x> :!exec_file %<CR>`

To pass the file name to a script I wrote which parses the extension and calls the appropriate interpreter, this works great so far.

However, I was wondering if I can call `bash` directly with the script name and have it execute it **since most scripts I edit have a shebang line**, so I tried this mapping instead:

`:map <C-x> :!bash %<CR>`

But it doesn't work, is it possible to execute a script by passing its name to bash ?

Comment: IIRC bash will try to execute Python scripts despite a different shebang line this way, so I'm not sure this actually makes sense. If your script file is executable, wouldn't `:!%` suffice?

Comment: @DanielBeck yes this is exactly what's happening, any way around that ? also not all scripts are executable and I don't want to chmod them...

Comment: Do the same thing the OS does when trying to execute a script file: Parse the shebang line to determine the interpreter, then call it. Essentially what your `exec_file` does, but without having to rely on the extension. Maybe use this only as a fallback when there's no shebang line. FWIW, shebang lines generally only make sense when you want to make a script executable, as calling interpreters will file arguments always works.

Comment: Your bash mapping works here. I use the following mapping to invoke shebang, assuming the script is executable: `map <f4> :!%:p<cr>`. `:p` will expand to the full path of the script.

Comment: @Thor yes but not all scripts I edit are executable yet, sometimes I open vim and write the script and want to execute before chmod'ing it or I open a non-executable script, but I think I understand now why bash doesn't execute the script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vim already uses a shell (see `:set shell?`) to execute the external command; scripts with shebang lines should work just fine. The canonical way to execute the current buffer is

```
:!./%
```

(Prepending `./` to deal with the current directory not being part of `PATH`. This assumes that the script is already executable (`:!chmod +x %`, maybe done in a mapping / ftplugin.)

You can re-execute with just `:!!`. Also, there are fancier solutions for executing (partial, unsaved, etc.) buffer contents in external interpreters; check the plugins section of [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/).

Comment: it seems that I have to chmod the script if I want this to work, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you probably need to chmod later anyway, so why not do this from the editor as you start writing it.

Comment: I was trying to save the extra step, anyway, I think I will stick to the script way and maybe edit it to read the shebang line as suggested by Daniel, this allows me to execute scripts that are non-executable or don't have a shebang at all.

Answer (score 0):

> seems that I have to chmod

no, you don't.  if your executable is of the form

```
#! /bin/bash
ls -l
```

the mapping

```
:map <C-x> :! sh ./% <CR>
```

will do what you want, even though the file is not executable.